# highcharts js. Как сделать скругленные концы?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

В опциях определено что `linecap: round`, но концы все равно не скругленные.

Код взят полностью с примера http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gauge-activity

Comment: Концы чего вы скруглять хотите?

Comment: Формы линии. Без бордеров

Comment: `linecap: round` подразумевает, что выставится свг-свойство `stroke-linecap=round`, как следует из его названия, оно относится к свойству `stroke`. данная диаграмма не рисуется при помощи `stroke`, она рисуется при помощи `path`, потому это свойство никак не относится к скруглению.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko Это тянет на полноценный ответ, а не на комментарий

Comment: @rjhdby ну, ответа на заданный вопрос это не предоставляет, потому решил вот так